# Using mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification:saveNotification I am not getting changes show up in main thread

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I am using a background thread to do a long running task including pulling data from service and insert records into the database via CoreData. As suggested by many answers here I am observing the `NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification` notification. I am using these 2 methods. In mergeChanges method I see my insertions in the notification object but after both methods complete my main MOC shows only changes prior to the background thread. Why is it not reflecting new changes from the background thread.  What am i missing?

```
- (void) registerContextDidSaveNotificationForManagedObjectContext:       (NSManagedObjectContext*) moc {
    NSNotificationCenter *nc = [NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter];
    [nc addObserver:self
           selector:@selector(mergeChanges:)
               name:NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification
             object:moc];
}

- (void)mergeChanges:(NSNotification *)notification {
    //AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    NSManagedObjectContext *mainContext = self.managedObjectContext;

    // Merge changes into the main context on the main thread
    [mainContext performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification:)
                                  withObject:notification
                               waitUntilDone:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The thread you register the `NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification` has to be the thread you invoke `[mainContext mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification: notification]`.

For example: you register thread A `NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification` when something change in thread B. Then you receive the notification, however, these changes are associated with thread B, you can not access the change directly, so you pass the notification as an argument to `mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification:` (which you send to the context on thread A) to merge these changes.

So please check whether they are on the same thread?

Comment: Thank you JohnMa,

They were in the same thread.  Now I have in ViewDidAppear

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [self registerContextDidSaveNotificationForManagedObjectContext:self.syncManagedObjectContext];
    
    [self getFullData];
}

Comment: Thank you JohnMa,

They were in the same thread.  Now I have in ViewDidAppear

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [self registerContextDidSaveNotificationForManagedObjectContext:self.syncManagedObjectContext];
    
    [self getFullData];
}

That is in main UI thread.  Then the getFullData method creates a new thread and inserts data. At the end of mergeChanges method I looked into mainContext.RegisteredObjects and I can see my newly inserted data but mainContext.InsertedObjects is empty.  I am not sure whether my data is there or not.  how do i best see what is a MOC object?

Comment: JohnMa, It was just me not able to

Comment: Your answer was the solution to my issue.  I was registering the notification in the background thread. Once i fixed that it was just me not knowing how to view entities in a moc object during debug while on a breakpoint.

Comment: So have you fixed that?